# Java Swings Sharing JTextField values across Tabs

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to share `JTextField` value across tabs.

I have 3 panels added to Tabbed Pane.When I enter some value in Text Feild in Tab1 and click on Tab3 I should be able to pass that  Text Feild  to Tab3.

The details of source code files are as follows.

In the file TTM.java

```
public class TTM extends JPanel {

    private void createBBT() {
        createDisplayD();
        pane.setBorder(null);
        pane.addTab("DisPlay", panel1);
        pane.addTab("Recall", panel2);
        createBen();
        pane.addTab("Ben", panel3);
    }

    public void createDisplayD() {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setOpaque(true);
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 255, 240)));
        panel1.add(new SComponent(user, region));
    }
}
```

And the Code in SComponent.java which is being called in the last line of above code block is as follows

```
public class SComponent extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener {

    public SComponent(String user, String region) {

        br = addTextField("br", 2, gridbag, v2, 
        ...);

   cu = addTextField("cu", 10, gridbag, v2,
        ...);

   search = new JButton("Search");
        search.setMnemonic('L');
        search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pmSearch();
            }
        });



    private void pmSearch() {

        sParams.put(Cu_Key, cu.getText());
        sParams.put(Br_Key, br.getText());

    }
}
```

So in the above code as we can see Cu and br values are added to a map and later used to fetch data from db.This happens in Tab 1.

But In Tab3 I should get these values and the details are as follows.

```
public class TTM extends JPanel {

    private void createBen() {
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setOpaque(true);
        panel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 255, 240)));
        panel3.add(new SBenComponent());
    }
}
```

So in the above context how can I get the value of cu and br which is in SComponent.java to either TTM.java file OR SBenComponent() (SBenComponent.java)which is in the last line of above code.

Thanks in Advance and  sorry if I have not stated the question clearly OR if its not a valid  question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly do something like this.

```
JTextField br, cu; //top of class

//inside method

   br = addTextField("br", 2, gridbag, v2, ...);

   cu = addTextField("cu", 10, gridbag, v2,...);
```

Then reference using class.br; or class.cu;

Answer (score 1):

> When I enter some value in Text Feild in Tab1 and click on Tab3 I should be able to pass that Text Feild to Tab3.

You can't pass components because a component can only belong to a single container. However you can share the model:

```
JTextField tab1TextField = new JTextField(...);
JTextField tab2TextField = new JTextField(...);
tab2TextField.setDocume( tab1TextField.getDocument() );
```

Now, when you enter text in either text field the other text field is automatically updated because they share the same Document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the **Mediator Pattern**. Its a singleton type object that you load up with references to root components. The mediadator then mediates calls to other distant GUI components.

You could also pass the highest component (ie. the frame) through the constructors of all panels. Then when you have a reference to the frame you can build in methods which access the other panels and components.